# "One registered product" on Steam?

Tags: steam

On the Steam badges, at the bottom it says "For having at least one product registered" but there's no "View Details" or anything to click on. It's greyed out, which sounds like I don't have this badge.

What is this badge and how can I make sure I have it? Most badges aren't retroactive I've found.

Comment: You get 100 XP for having a product registered.  Chances are good, as long as you've bought a game, you're good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Steam has a two-tiered system for user accounts.

An account that is just registered, but doesn't have a paid product on it is considered a [**Limited User Account**](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=3330-IAGK-7663) and has some restrictions placed on it - mostly community-related. This is for security reasons.

**Please note**:

The previous "one product registered" badge has been replaced by the Game Collector Badge in the [update on June 18th '13](http://steamcommunity.com/groups/tradingcards#announcements/detail/1837748658627226301):

> **Game Collector Badge:** There's a new badge which will grant you XP based on how many games you have in your Steam library. This badge replaces the "100 XP for having at least one product registered" message at the bottom of the badges page.

---

*The following information is now outdated, but will be kept for reference as the question itself is no longer relevant.*

This is not a badge per se, it is just a way for Steam to list it under the XP granting activities. It doesn't have an image and it doesn't have any special text to it - it's just that:

> 100 XP
>   For having at least one product registered

You, therefore, receive 100XP just for being a real person in the eyes of Steam. Congratulations!